# DragEnter event on object with AllowDrop=False

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

Is it possible to get a dragEnter event on a window with allowDrop=False? I want the user to drop the file in a little box which will show up when he drags something into the application.

Is this possible and how?

BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the best way to get answer is make a question. I found out a way to do this. First it have to allow drop. When drag enter I set allow drop to false.

Answer (score 0):

Drag-and-drop operations are not enabled by default, and must be enabled deliberately by setting AllowDrop to true. See MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.allowdrop.aspx

So to get that event you have to set AllowDrop=True